# strcmp usage to terminate file writing doesn't work

Tags: c, file, strcmp

I write the following code to write a text. strcmp is supposed to terminate the file writing when the user type #. Still doesn't do it and i cannot exit the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c[100];
    fp = fopen ("/home/smksx/Desktop/uniprograms/domes/arxeio2","w");
    printf ("\n\nWrite your text\n\n");
    printf ("\n\nTerminate with #\n\n");
    while (strcmp(c,"#")!=0)
        {
        scanf ("%s",&c);
        if (strcmp(c,"#")!=0)
            {
            fprintf (fp,"%s",c);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you input text? Do you include # in text, or separately?

Comment: Maybe the read in string will also have the line ending so therefore they are not equal?

Comment: And just a little note: when scanf-ing text, you do not use & sign: it should be `scanf("%s", c)`

Comment: First time through the loop, the `c` buffer is uninitialized; this is a bug.

Comment: My favorite: `while (fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin) && strcmp("#\n", c)) fprintf(fp, "%s", c)`

Comment: "Still doesn't do it " --> lacks detail.  Post what was entered, what was seen, what was expected.

Answer (score 2):

you have several issues in your code:

1. c is pointer to char, so you may not use & in scanf
2. your while loop is checkin uninitialized data
3. scanf reads up to the \n, and not adding it to the file

here's what you code could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c[100];
    fp = fopen ("/home/smksx/Desktop/uniprograms/domes/arxeio2","w");
    printf ("\n\nWrite your text\n\n");
    printf ("\n\nTerminate with #\n\n");
    while (1) // c is not initialized, so do not check it's content here
    {
        scanf ("%s",c);        // c is pointer to char, so no & here
        if (strcmp(c,"#")!=0)  // here c is safe to be checked
        {
            fprintf (fp,"%s\n",c);  // you may be adding a \n here
        }
        else 
            break;     // do not repeat yourself: no need to double strcmp
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a bad place to use `while (scanf(...) == 1)` to let invalid input end the loop.

Comment: Detail "c is pointer to char" --> `c` is an _array_.  In `scanf ("%s",c);`, `c` is converted to the address and type of the first element, a `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

If `strcmp` is not giving the desired results, try `strchr` to find a `#`.
Use the precision field, `%.*s`, to print up to the `#`. The asterisk allows for an variable precision as one of the arguments to `printf`.
If word by word processing is preferred over line by line, swap the comment on the `while` statements to use `scanf` instead of `fgets`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char input[100] = "";
    char *find = NULL;

    //while ( 1 == scanf ( "%99s", input)) {//process word by word, no spaces
    while ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
        input[strcspn ( input, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
        if ( ( find = strchr ( input, '#'))) {//find a # in input
            if ( find != input) {//not the first character
                printf ( "%.*s\n", (int)(find - input), input);//print up to #
            }
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf ( "%s\n", input);//did not find #
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There some problems in your code:

1. You cannot use '&' when getting input char array (i.e. string). You have to use `scanf("%s", c)` instead.
2. As `scanf` "ignores" spaces, I would recommend you to use `fgets`. So your final code can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c[100] = { 0 }; // init to empty string

    fp = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    printf("\n\nWrite your text\n\n");
    printf("\n\nTerminate with #\n\n");

    while (strcmp(c, "#") != 0)
    {
        fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);

        if (strcmp(c, "#\n") != 0) //fgets includes new line character too
            fprintf(fp, "%s", c);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

`fgets` function reads whole line of text (without danger of overflow), so it is easier than `scanf`

Moreover, I would not recommend you to use full path when creating file, because, in other systems, it might fail (I had to change it under Windows)

Comment: Please do not recommend `gets`. It is no longer a standard C function, see [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) At least with `scanf` you can restrict the input length, for example `scanf ("%99s", c);`

Comment: It isn't suitable *at all*: it is obsolete , and `fgets` is better.

Comment: But from a security point of view, `gets()` is as good (bad) as `scanf("%s", ...)`.

Comment: Unlike `scanf` the length restriction for `fgets` *includes* the nul terminator. Also, the string won't be equal to `"#"` until the newline is removed. Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: Off by 1.  `fgets(c, 100, stdin);` is OK.  `fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin);` better.

Answer (score 0):

Initially in the condition of the loop

```
while (strcmp(c,"#")!=0)
```

there is used uninitialized variable `c`. So the program has undefined behavior. 
In this call of the function `scanf`

```
scanf ("%s",&c);
```

the type of the second argument is incorrect. The type of the expression &c is `char ( * )[100]` while the function expects that the second argument has the type `char *`.

Also you should check 1) whether the file was opened successfully and 2) the user does not interrupt the input in the array.

Instead of the scanf  that reads until a white space is encountered when the conversion specifier %s is used it is much better to use the standard function fgets.

Also if you are writing to a text file then it is desirable to append each record with the new line character.

The main part of the program can look the following way.

```
if ( fp != NULL )
{
    while ( fgets( c, sizeof( c ), stdin ) != NULL && strcmp( c, "#" ) != 0 )
    {
        fprintf ( fp, "%s", c );
    } 
}
```

Pay attention to that fgets appends the new line character to the entered string provided that the string with the new line character can be accommodated in the character array.